# Thunderbird 68.3.1 Profile-How to install in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: thunderbird

I want to move from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 18.04, and have transferred most files to do so.

But I have 14GB of Thunderbird email data which is crucial. The Windows 7 Thunderbird profile is from Thunderbird 68.3.1. It refuses to load in Ubuntu, whose Thunderbird is 68.2.2. It gives a message saying that the profile from Windows 7 is from a newer version of Thunderbird than 68.2.2, and that I need that newer version.

I cannot find that newer version in the repositories.

What should I do?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can try downgrading your profile from the terminal by launching Thunderbird as follows:

```
thunderbird --allow-downgrade
```

Please make sure you backup your profile just in case something goes wrong during the downgrade. Upon successful conversion, ensure everything is in place and check for updates for your addons (if any) then close Thunderbird.

Future launches should now work out of the box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I need to specify the name of the profile.default file? If so, what is the command syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment since I do not have enough reputation.

Now regarding your question:

> Do I need to specify the name of the profile.default file? If so, what is the command syntax?

I believe it works on the currently active default profile. You can either navigate to the .thunderbird folder located in your home directory and delete all profiles except the one you want to downgrade (will possibly be something like default-release but double check) or use:

```
thunderbird --Profilemanager
```

to set the default profile. Then use the downgrade command to downgrade the profile.

Again please make sure to backup everything just in case.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH. IT WORKED. Moved all .default drives but the transfer one out of the .thunderbird file to a temporary file (this was the backup). Ran thunderbird -p at terminal to run Profile Manager. Then at terminal ran thunderbird --allow-downgrade. Then launched Thunderbird. Just needed to enter passwords for getting and sending mail. Your advice was INDISPENSABLE. Thank you again.